# Right-click on anchor not showing expected context menu in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, web

I've got the following HTML:

```
<a href="somewhere">
    <span class='mask'></span>
    <img src="my_image.jpg" />
</a>
```

and the following CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

a:hover .mask{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.mask {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And, visually, it works as expected. The `<a>`, when hovered, shows a semi-transparent *mask* over itself.

However, in every browser except IE, when I right-click on the `<a>`, it works as expected — I see a context menu for links.

But in IE, I see the context menus for as if I had right-clicked on any other static item in the page. I'm looking for a way to make the context menus work as expected in IE.

Cheers!

Comment: What version of IE? Just tested IE10 and seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/2unNW/

Comment: Worked for me as well IE 7 and 8

Comment: IE 7, 8 and 9 are busted for me. I'll add a jsfiddle to repro.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in IE 9 - add z-index: -1 to `.mask`. Although the z-index will affect your masking visual.

```
.mask {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/osegib/1/edit#/osegib/2/edit

Comment: Would you mind using opacity filters on the image instead? Is the same mask covering multiple images?